# My staff attacked my jack russell

Tags: dogs, health, injury

They both got along great for past 3 years, usually it's my jack russell that nips my staff, but I was dreading the day it happened the other way around, last night it did, my staff is 8 and has slowed down, she's had a very active life, and is due in season very soon, they both are, she's now getting old and grumpy and just doesn't want to be mithered, jack Russel is 6 and a happy go lucky scatterbrain:)

Last night we woke up the sound of our jack Russel screaming, they've been sleeping in the same large dog bed for the past 3 years, they're inseparable, they've had arguments in the past but usually they resolve their differences with the jack Russell yapping and maybe a quick nip but nothing to do any damage to my staff.

I'm concerned as jack Russell has a puncture wound under her jaw but doesn't seem to have gone into her mouth it took me around 45 mins to stem the bleeding from both wounds bathing them and flushing them with salt water, what can I do for her at home in terms of treatment, I don't think she needs stitches and has happily let me clean the wounds, she's understandably​ shaken up, her best buddy's just bit her, but she's eating, and drinking normally and going toilet fine. We've separated them for wounds to heal, treatment from a vets is virtually impossible as after moving home we're completely broke right now.

Can anyone give me advice please in terms of her head wound and does it need to be stitched or glued?

[image]

Comment: How is your dog doing? I hope the wounds are healing.

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't look like it needs to be stitched or glued. Best bathe it with an antiseptic wash made for pet wounds and then apply a cream to assist with healing.

There's [many products on the market](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=antiseptic%20wash%20for%20dogs&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU738AU738&oq=anticeptic%20w&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.11132j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). A [chlorhexidine](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=chlorhexidine%20wash&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU738AU738&oq=chlorhe&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8045j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or [betadine](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=betadine&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU738AU738&oq=betadine%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7435j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) based product would do the trick for the cleaning. As there are [many creams suitable for treating wounds in dogs](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=wound%20cream%20for%20dogs&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU738AU738&oq=wound%20cream%20for%20dogs&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.4598j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

The other recommendation I would have is to make sure her worming vaccinations are up to date and that her diet is healthy. These all assist in sustaining a healthy immune system and promote healing and to help prevent or fight any infections.

It is important to take your dog to the vet to be checked, as it's impossible to know definitively if the dog will be ok. The vet can prescribe any antibiotics if needed.

Lastly and most importantly, lots of cuddles and love.

Feel free to come back with any questions of help with dealing with the behaviour between them.

Comment: @Pieces876 sorry I used 'he' will update to 'she'. She looks like a real sweetheart. Best of luck with her.

Comment: @Pieces876 yes that could well be the reason that she's snapped, if she's in pain. Poor thing. Sounds like you're an awesome owner. I hope to see you again and here how your girls are going :)

Comment: Downvoter, feedback? I'd like to improve the post. Is it the links to google searches? I did that, as we're global and didn't want to recommend a product, but I can add more details. I want the quality of the posts here to be good.

Comment: Yvette – I downvoted this and I apologise for not providing feedback at the time. My main concern was that it's impossible to say whether the wound needs veterinary care, and that the OP may take your answer to mean they did not need to take the dog to the vet. There may be internal injury that you can't see, more than just a puncture wound. It will likely get infected without antibiotics but I agree antimicrobial wash to clean the wound is likely the best thing if the OP will not take the dog to a veterinarian. Will remove my downvote if you edit it to say the dog really needs to see a vet.

Comment: @HarryV. sure and thanks for the feedback. It's good to hear. I thought it was the links.. so it's really good you told me cheers

Answer (score 1):

Our Jack Russell is absolutely fine, so I thought I'd provide an answer based on the treatment regime we used. I repeatedly washed the wound with salt water 3 times a day until it closed up, applying antiseptic wilkos own brand antiseptic cream, there's no damage to her mouth either, so I've likely saved myself a good few £ by treating her at home.

Looking at the top of her head now you wouldn't even tell she ever had a wound, they're back to being best of friends, and I hope they continue to be so for those that said "take her to a vet"  I'm glad I didn't, a vet's treatment would have been an unnecessary expense in this case.

Comment: I'm glad you got lucky and the wound responded well to home treatment!

Comment: @Zaralynda so am I it could have been much worse